# Installing haskell ghc fails

Tags: windows-7, installation, haskell, ghc

I am trying to install `Haskell-2012.4.0.0.exe` on my computer running windows 7.

When I run the installer I get the following message and the installation fails,

```
Installer integrity check has failed. Common causes include
incomplete download and damaged media. Contact the
installer's author to obtain a new copy.

More information at:
http://nsis.sf.net/NSIS_Error
```

How do I fix this issue and get it to install?

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests what is wrong - `incomplete download and damaged media`; Get a new copy! For what ever reason, it may appear that your download was not successful (maybe your internet connection dropped during download). So, re-download the installer and then try to install again.

Comment: I used the same installer to install it on another machine running windows 7 and it worked without any issues.

Comment: Well, if you've tried again to install it and it still fails then consider your firewall or AV or any other similar programs (or even permissions)

Comment: I have been able to install haskell successfully. I found that changing the usb I used to copy the haskell setup installer from my computer to my usb to install on another computer fixed the issue. It seems that when I am copying the file to the usb, that it is not completely getting copying.

Comment: You didn't mention this in your original post :-)